# SQL Reporting Services: Linked Report Parameters Not Updating

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, sql-server-2016

I have a report in SSRS 2016 that is linked in several locations to allow our management team to pull data for their respective business units.  The report has a static list of parameter values which are used to auto generate the default date. I have updated the report definition to include a new list parameter but the linked reports do not contain the updated value.  I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/53daa41e-7e56-4343-baf6-89b84bec25b0/linked-report-will-not-get-updated-automatically-when-original-report-is-updated?forum=sqlreportingservices) article which also describes the scenario and but I am looking for a way to update the linked report parameters without deleting the linked report and recreating it because if I delete it, it would delete the associated subscriptions. The first image below is the base report and the second is the listing in the linked report.

[image] [image]

Comment: Also please note that the report definition in the linked report did update appropriately, just not the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

The workaround I found was to create an extra parameter in the report that is not referenced in any code and then deploy it to the server.  The change to the parameters will cause a refresh to all the linked instances as well as the base report.  After deployment you can then remove the parameter.

Comment: Great answer to what is, in my opinion, a pretty substantial bug in SSRS.